# Find pdf given moments (well first by finding mgf!)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Suppose a continuous random variable has odd moments = zero and even moments as follows

$$E[X^{2n}] = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$$

Then the mgf is, by Maclaurin series expansion where we can switch sum and integral by nonnegativity of integrand,

$$E[e^{tX}] = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)!} \frac{(2n)! t^{2n}}{2^n n!}$$

whose closed form is [standard normal](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n%20%3D%200%20to%20infinity%20(t%5E(2n))%2F((2%5E(n))((n)!))) as pointed out in answer, sort of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an error. You should be careful when writing sums.

This is the central normal distribution you have to guess.

Indeed let $G$ be a gaussian $G\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$:

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tG}]=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}t^n\frac{\mathbb{E}[G^n]}{n!}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{t^{2k}}{k!2^k}$$
 I identify same powers of $t^k$
If $n=2k+1$, then by rhs I have $E[G^{2k+1}]=0$
if $n=2k$, then I got: $$\frac{E[G^n]}{n!}=\frac{E[G^{2k}]}{(2k)!}=\frac{1}{k!2^k}$$

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_normale#Moments

Comment: Oh I get it. It should be 2n not n/2. Thanks ^-^